# When does $E(X I(X < a)) = E(X)P(X < a) $?

Tags: probability

I know that $X$ and $I(X<a)$ isn't independent so you cannot split the expectation. But is there some inequalities that gives you this result, or $E(X I(X < a)) \leq E(X)P(X < a)$ (or $\geq$)? Thanks.

Comment: what is $I(X<a)$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume $I(X < a)$ is the indicator function of $X < a$.  Write $X = Y + Z$ where $Y = X I(X < a)$ and $Z = X I(X \ge a)$.  With probability $p = P(X<a)$ we have $X = Y < a$ and $Z = 0$, while with probability $1-p$ we have
$X=Z \ge a$ and $Y = 0$.  Now (if $0 < p < 1$) $E[Y] = p E[X|X<a]$ while $E[Z] = (1-p) E[X|X\ge a] $.  So 
$$E[X] P(X<a) - E[X I(X<a)] = p E[X] - E[Y] = p E[Z] - (1-p) E[Y] = p(1-p)(E[X|X\ge a] - E[X|X < a]) \ge 0$$
with equality only if $p=0$ or $p=1$.